# Using an Android phone as a wifi headset for Windows

Tags: voip

Here is the issue:

- I am working from home and want to use my wired headset on both my work computer and personal computer (not at the same time) without having to plug/unplug it every time
- I prefer wifi over Bluetooth because of superior range and bandwidth
- I have an old Galaxy Note4 and would like to plug my headset into it and be able to switch from one PC to the other

I have found solutions allowing to use the phone as a webcam or mic which would cover half of my needs (DroidCam...) and apps that send audio from the Windows PC to the phone (SoundIt...) but no app allowing to do both at the same time from a single app.
I could potentially use Windows "Listen" functionalities to create bridges between a VOIP client and the main sound card on the PC but this is a bit tedious and I am concerned this might add unnecessary latency.

Ideally, my dream app would:
- Create sound devices for playback and recording on the PC

- Have a server app on the PC forwarding audio between the client on the phone and the local audio devices (allowing me to dial from the PC using Skype or other solution and get sound to/from my phone)
- Have a client app on Android that would send mic and receive speaker audio of the phone to/from the selected server.

While it seems like a rather easy thing to implement, I cannot find any satisfactory solution. Any suggestion?